# Yii2 - action method handling post from another component

Tags: php, yii2

my code is like -in my controller:

```
public function actionCheckout(){
 if (Yii::$app->request->post())  {
     if($_POST['payment-method']==4){
     $_POST=[];

                $params=[
                    'id'=>'1000',
                    'amount'=> '121',
                    'email'=>'pkjoshi.sbp@gmail.com',
                    'firstname'=>'pawan',
                    'phone'=>'9937253528',
                    'productinfo'=>'55'
                ];

                Yii::$app->TechProcess->TechProcessCheckout($params);
     }
    }
  }
```

and the code of my controller is like:

```
namespace common\components\paynimo;

  class TechProcess extends Component{

   public function TechProcessCheckout($params){

  if($_POST && isset($_POST['amount'])){

    $val = $_POST;
    $session = new Session;
    $session->open();
    $session['iv'] =$val['iv'];
    $session['key'] =$val['key'];
   // $_SESSION['iv'] = $val['iv'];
   // $_SESSION['key']   = $val['key'];
...
```

and a form in the component itself which submits to self

The problem is as my action is already handling a post request for selection of payment method, I am not able to make it handle another post from form from component.

how I can overcome this?

full text of component function:

```
public function TechProcessCheckout(){

if($_POST && isset($_POST['amount'])){

$val = $_POST;
$session = new Session;
$session->open();
$session['iv'] =$val['iv'];
$session['key'] =$val['key'];
// $_SESSION['iv'] = $val['iv'];
// $_SESSION['key']   = $val['key'];

$transactionRequestBean = new TransactionRequestBean();

//Setting all values here
//$transactionRequestBean->setMerchantCode($val['mrctCode']);
$transactionRequestBean->merchantCode = $val['mrctCode'];
$transactionRequestBean->accountNo = $val['tpvAccntNo'];
$transactionRequestBean->ITC = $val['itc'];
$transactionRequestBean->mobileNumber = $val['mobNo'];
$transactionRequestBean->customerName = $val['custname'];
$transactionRequestBean->requestType = $val['reqType'];
$transactionRequestBean->merchantTxnRefNumber = $val['mrctTxtID'];
$transactionRequestBean->amount = $val['amount'];
$transactionRequestBean->currencyCode = $val['currencyType'];
$transactionRequestBean->returnURL = $val['returnURL'];
$transactionRequestBean->s2SReturnURL = $val['s2SReturnURL'];
$transactionRequestBean->shoppingCartDetails = $val['reqDetail'];
$transactionRequestBean->txnDate = $val['txnDate'];
$transactionRequestBean->bankCode = $val['bankCode'];
$transactionRequestBean->TPSLTxnID = $val['tpsl_txn_id'];
$transactionRequestBean->custId = $val['custID'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardId = $val['cardID'];
$transactionRequestBean->key = $val['key'];
$transactionRequestBean->iv = $val['iv'];
$transactionRequestBean->webServiceLocator = $val['locatorURL'];
$transactionRequestBean->MMID = $val['mmid'];
$transactionRequestBean->OTP = $val['otp'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardName = $val['cardName'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardNo = $val['cardNo'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardCVV = $val['cardCVV'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardExpMM = $val['cardExpMM'];
$transactionRequestBean->cardExpYY = $val['cardExpYY'];
$transactionRequestBean->timeOut = (!empty($val['timeOut']) ? $val['timeOut'] : 30 );

$url = $transactionRequestBean->getTransactionToken();

$responseDetails = $transactionRequestBean->getTransactionToken();
$responseDetails = (array)$responseDetails;
$response = $responseDetails[0];

if(is_string($response) && preg_match('/^msg=/',$response)){
    $outputStr = str_replace('msg=', '', $response);
    $outputArr = explode('&', $outputStr);
    $str = $outputArr[0];

    $transactionResponseBean = new TransactionResponseBean();
    $transactionResponseBean->setResponsePayload($str);
    $transactionResponseBean->setKey($val['key']);
    $transactionResponseBean->setIv($val['iv']);

    $response = $transactionResponseBean->getResponsePayload();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    exit;
 }elseif(is_string($response) && preg_match('/^txn_status=/',$response)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    exit;
}

echo "<script>window.location = '".$response."'</script>";
ob_flush();

}else if($_POST){

$response = $_POST;
// var_dump($response);exit;

if(is_array($response)){
    $str = $response['msg'];
}else if(is_string($response) && strstr($response, 'msg=')){
    $outputStr = str_replace('msg=', '', $response);
    $outputArr = explode('&', $outputStr);
    $str = $outputArr[0];
}else {

    $str = $response;
}

$transactionResponseBean = new TransactionResponseBean();

$transactionResponseBean->setResponsePayload($str);
$transactionResponseBean->key = $_SESSION['key'];
$transactionResponseBean->iv = $_SESSION['iv'];

$response = $transactionResponseBean->getResponsePayload();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "<br><br><br><br>";

//session_destroy();
$session->close();
?>
<?php { ?>

<a href='<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>'>GO TO HOME</a>

<?php
exit;
}
?>



<html>
<body>
<form id="techprocess" method="post">

    <table class="tbl" width="60%" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="40%">Field Description</th>
        <th width="20%">Field Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Request Type</label>o</td>
        <td><select name="reqType">
            <option value="T">T</option>
            <option value="S">S</option>
            <option value="O">O</option>
            <option value="R">R</option>
            <option value="TNR">TNR</option>
            <option value="TCI">TCI</option>
            <option value="TWC">TWC</option>
            <option value="TRC">TRC</option>
            <option value="TCC">TCC</option>
            <option value="TWI">TWI</option>
            <option value="TIC">TIC</option>
            <option value="TIO">TIO</option>
            <option value="TWD">TWD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Merchant Code</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mrctCode" value="T245107"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Merchant Transaction ID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mrctTxtID" value="<?php echo $this->strNo; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Currency Code</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="currencyType" value="INR"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Amount</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Client Meta Data</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="itc" value="NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Request Detail</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="reqDetail" value="INST_1.0_0.0"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Transaction Date</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txnDate" value="<?php echo $this->strCurDate;?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Bank Code</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bankCode" value="470"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Locator URL</label></td>
        <td><select name="locatorURL">
                <option value="https://www.tekprocess.co.in/PaymentGateway/TransactionDetailsNew.wsdl">TEST</option>
                <option value="http://10.10.60.46:8080/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">E2EWithIP</option>
                <option value="https://tpslvksrv6046/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">E2EWithDomain</option>
                <option value="https://www.tekprocess.co.in/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">UATWithDomain</option>
                <option value="http://10.10.102.157:8081/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">UATWithIP</option>
                <option value="http://10.10.102.158:8081/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">EAP UATWithIP</option>
                <option selected value="https://www.tpsl-india.in/PaymentGateway/TransactionDetailsNew.wsdl">LIVE</option>
                <option value="http://10.10.60.247:8080/PaymentGateway/services/TransactionDetailsNew">Linux E2E</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>S2S URL </label></td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" name="s2SReturnURL" value="https://tpslvksrv6046/LoginModule/Test.jsp"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>TPSL Transaction ID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tpsl_txn_id" value="<?php echo 'TXN00'.rand(1,10000); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><label>Card ID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardID" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Customer ID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="custID" value="19`enter code here`2627"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Customer Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="custname" value="test"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Timeout</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="timeOut" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Mobile Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mobNo" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Account Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="accNo" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Tpv Account Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="tpvAccntNo" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>MMID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mmid" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>OTP</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="otp" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Transaction Type</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="TxnType" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Transaction SubType</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="TxnSubType" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Card name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardName" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Card Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardNo" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Card CVV Number</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardCVV" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Card Exp MM</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardExpMM" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Card Exp YY</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cardExpYY" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Key</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="key" value="663621GPLFAX"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>IV</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="iv" value="6014051IBXWQV"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Return URL </label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="returnURL" value='<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
     <!--   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> -->
         <script>document.getElementById("techprocess").submit();</script> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php  }} } ?>
```

Comment: its really hard to understand what you are trying to say, can you rephrase? and i see that you have `Yii::$app->TechProcess->TechProcessCheckout($params);` in you action then why you need to still use `$_POST` in the component , just pass the post array to the component fromt he action

Comment: Hi Omer - you are right. some of the parameters I can pass to the component, but the form in the component is huge. let me post the form here, which is part of the component.

Comment: is the above html code inside the componenet function ?

Comment: Yes Omer. but I think you are right. as I don't need to display the form to the user, most of the values I can pull from either from action -params or from setting table, wherever necessary, leaving the form as redundant. or please suggest any other better option.

Comment: i have'nt quiet understood the flow that you are trying to achieve but having an html form inside the component is totally redundant and not a conventional approach for sure, but at them moment i cant suggest anything as i don't know what is the actual application flow you are trying to achieve, a user story that describes the flow will help

Comment: Hi Omer - Thanks for your support. it is about payment-gateway Integration. I have received the Integration kit from the aggregator, which included that form in the main processing file and I wanted that to port the kit in Yii2. Now I removed the form and included all mandatory params either through settings or controller parameters as you suggested. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi Omer - can you please take a look at this question I have posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136174/yii2-swiftmailer-adding-multiple-dynamic-records-per-user

Comment: Hello Joshi - There are quite a lot of problems with your approach. If you are truly dealing with real credit card data on a public website, I would be very worried about your approach. This does not look safe.