# Yii2 - Swiftmailer - adding multiple dynamic records per user

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

The setup is like this:

I have users/clients who book classes. Classes can be multiple classes per date and per location and per instructor.

Now there is a need to cancel the bookings for unavoidable reasons for specific location.So I added a table `site_closure` with `location_name`, `start_date` and `end_date`, and in the controller update the order_item `status` as `cancelled` against all the bookings for the dates posted in `site_closure`

Next step is I need to send the mail to user/client detailing the list of classes cancelled.

so in my site_closure controller create action I have added this code:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new SiteClosure();
        $st = Yii::$app->getTable;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            $order_items= OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
            $users_id_array = OrderItem::find()->select('distinct(user_id)')->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->asArray()->all();
            $users_id = array_values($users_id_array[0]);
            $users=implode(',',$users_id);
            $client_emails = User::find()->where(['in','user.id' ,$users])->asArray()->all();

           // var_dump($client_emails);exit;

            foreach($order_items as $order_item){
                $order_item->cancellation_status="cancelled";

                $order_item->save();
               // $user_id.=$order_item->user_id;

            }
            $model->save();

            $from_email = $st->settings('email', 'from_email');
            $from_name = $st->settings('email', 'from_name');


            foreach( $client_emails as  $client_email){
                $cancelled_items=OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name] and ['user_id'=>$client_email['id']])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
                $start_time='';
                foreach($cancelled_items as $cancelled_item){
                    $cancelled_item->date;
                    $start_time.=$cancelled_item->start_time;

                }
            \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                ->setFrom([$from_email => $from_name])
                ->setTo($client_email['email'])
                ->setSubject('Regarding Cancellation of Classes')
                ->setHtmlBody(
                'regarding cancellation '.$cancelled_item->date .'<br>'.
                $start_time                
                )
                ->send();

            }          


            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

If I iterate the `\Yii::$app->mailer->compose()` in `foreach`, it will send mail for each class, whereas I want all classes cancelled for that user in single mail.

update:
while @weegee solution is working as expected, but I think I have missed something in my code as you can see in the attached images, I have 3 classes cancelled.
[image]

but the mail sent is for all the classes in the picture for 22nd July.
like:
regarding cancellation
Date    Start Time
2019-07-22  09:50:00
2019-07-22  09:00:00
2019-07-22  09:20:00
2019-07-22  10:00:00
2019-07-22  10:10:00

[image]

my update code looks like this:

foreach( $client_emails as  $client_email){
                $cancelled_items=OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name] and ['user_id'=>$client_email['id'] and ['cancellation_status'=>'cancelled']])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
                $body = "regarding cancellation";
                $body .= "DateStart Time";
                foreach($cancelled_items as $cancelled_item){

```
                $body.="<tr><td>".$cancelled_item->date  ."</td><td>". $cancelled_item->start_time."</td></tr>";

            }
            $body.="</table>";
```

but still it is including all the classes for 22July.

Comment: Why not use `$client_email['id']` inside the forEach to get details about the canceled classes and send them emails under that?

Comment: are you trying to send a single email to all the users in `$client_emails` against whom there is any `$cancelled_items` ?, apart from all this why you are using s separate table for cancelling the order, cant you manage it with a `tinyint` or an `enum` column type within the `orderItem` table

Comment: Hi Omer - like say user - A has 3 classes cancelled for 24-July. so he will get one mail like your classes on 24-07-2019  start-time -9.10AM, 24-07-2019 start-time - 9-.30AM and 24-07-2019 start-time -.9.50AM . like wise I have a site closure from 23-july to 27th July, so if that user is having more classes in those dates will include in that mail.

Comment: @weegee - added column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save all the time for a client in a string, in a list and then use that in the email

```php
foreach( $client_emails as  $client_email){
    $cancelled_items=OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name] and ['user_id'=>$client_email['id']])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();
    $body = "regarding cancellation 
    <ul>"; // create the ul element
    foreach($cancelled_items as $cancelled_item){
        $start_time = $cancelled_item->start_time;
        $body .= "<li>". $start_time."</li>"; // add the li with the start_time content inside
    }
    $body .= "</ul>"; // close the list
    \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom([$from_email => $from_name])
    ->setTo($client_email['email'])
    ->setSubject('Regarding Cancellation of Classes')
    ->setHtmlBody($body)
    ->send();
}
```

Don't fetch the users which have the cancellation status not set to canceled. Edit your `$orders` variable like this

```php
$order_items = OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name])
->andwhere(['between', 'date', '', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])
->andWhere("cancellation_status=:cancellation_status",array(':cancellation_status'=>'cancelled'))->all();
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is what I need. let me try.

Comment: This would send email to all the users irrespective if they have classes cancelled ot not

Comment: @weegee - yes the mail contents are formatted as expected, but I think I have missed some other point in my code, which is including extra classes then the cancelled classes.

Comment: @weegee - I doesn't quite understand the query you have suggested. as you can see, I am setting the status cancelled subsequently like - `foreach($order_items as $order_item){
                $order_item->cancellation_status="cancelled";
                $order_item->save();
            }` so how I can get the status before saving the status as cancelled.

Comment: No, to update data in the database, you have to update it in the MySQL database, not in the variables themselves. You have to fetch only the users who have canceled, So fetch for them by `andWhere("cancellation_status=:cancellation_status",array(':cancellation_status'=>'cancelled'))->all();` This is a placeholder statement. I suggest you read https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php and I also suggest reading the docs to  grasp what is being the source of confusion here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record @Joshi

Comment: Thanks weegee. I will sure read that. so you mean I need to update just that query or made changes elsewhere as well?

Comment: Hi weegee - just updated that, but no luck, I am still getting 5 class instead of 3. please see if you can any other issue else I will find it. but the main issue for which I posted the question is resolved, hence I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Hi Weegee - I just saw the debugger - and from query - `$cancelled_items=OrderItem::find()->where(['location_id'=>$model->location_name] and ['user_id'=>$client_email['id'] and ['cancellation_status'=>'cancelled']])->andwhere(['between', 'date', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all(); `  - and `['user_id'=>$client_email['id'] and ['cancellation_status'=>'cancelled']])` are ignored. am I missing something in the syntax here?

Comment: @Joshi try `$order_items = OrderItem::find()->where("location_id=:location_id",array(':location_id'=>$model->location_name))
->andWhere("cancellation_status=:cancellation_status",array(':cancellation_status'=>'cancelled'))->andwhere(['between', 'date', '', $model->from_date, $model->to_date ])->all();`